# USB Key for Mac & Windows to Autoload Content?

Tags: windows, macos, air, usb, adobe

I'm looking to find out a clean method of deploying a USB key to a customer, that once inserted into the computer (both Mac and Windows), will auto load a respective "thing".

The "thing" could be either an application, a PDF, a splash page (html) in a web browser (system default browser), or potentially an AIR application. The problem with AIR is that I'd need the user to install AIR potentially. Since AIR is platform independent, that could work out pretty well I'd think.

I have established what will be my windows autorun.inf, to load up either AIR, or a portable browser with the splash page. And on the Mac, the user will get a folder (with a graphic background) and a link to launch the page (in a browser, or the portable browser all together). I'm looking for best practices for something like this ultimately.

Comment: I'll append the question here which is whether you can auto load a folder in OS X with a background image and app icon to open? I know when you double click on a disk on the desktop for example, it can do that, or when you mount a DMG.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Autorun isn't generally possible anymore because of the negative security implications.

You're better off making sure that your disk image is set to open a finder window on load, and that the background encourages people to (manually) run your content.

A similar option to an AIR app, but with even less overhead, are Flash projectors.  They have fewer features, but are portable and lightweight.

Comment: I'll check that out for sure (I was mid stream editing my original post when you replied, sorry). I have the autorun.inf setup essentially, and will create a test case for the Mac side of things. I'll also check out flash projectors now and see what that's all about. Thank you.

Comment: I guess the question right now then is, creating flash projectors (for each platform), where the executable is a web page, not just a piece of multimedia. Possible? That could eliminate overhead for me using portable browsers.

Comment: I have a USB stick here that autoruns on my MacBook running OSX 10.8.4 - when you insert it, Safari automatically runs and loads a webpage. I'm curious to know how they're doing it, but the device doesn't appear in Disk Utility (even with Debug/List All Disks).

Comment: Apparently it's a Webkey as outlined here: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4563230